# Handling Ajax request with Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

We have a typical situation. On selecting a drop down, there is an loading icon over the browser. So if I am testing anything manually, it will make the user wait. However Selenium browser plugin does not record this loading screen. And thus script continues to fill up next set of HTML elements.  Now when the loading is done and server comes back the next set of selected parameters get over written. In the end one of the parameters will give element not found. How do we ensure that selenium script waits exactly till the server responds back or the loading icon goes away.
We have tried several things before posting like waitforElement, waitforCondition. While former didn't do the trick, we are having issues executing later.
Let me know if more details are required.
Thanks,
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

waitForCondition  |  selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().$.active==0  | 20000

Klendathu